# Django error `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "user-detail"`

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am getting the common DRF hyperlinked model-detail error, and I'd like to understand what it means so I stop getting it.

The view is as such:

```
import json
import time

from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework import serializers, viewsets

from utils.general import unpack_request_body
from .models import Restaurant


#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

class RestaurantSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    # answered by bovenson:
    #   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20550598/django-rest-framework-could-not-resolve-url-for-hyperlinked-relationship-using
    # what just happened here? idk what HyperlinkedIdentityField does
    url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name="restaurant:restaurant-detail")
    class Meta:
        model = Restaurant
        fields = '__all__'


class RestaurantViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Restaurant.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RestaurantSerializer

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

def find_restaurant_owned_by_a_username(username):
    try:
        user = User.objects.get(username=username)
    except:
        return None
    restaurants_owned = user.restaurants.all()
    if restaurants_owned:
        return restaurants_owned[0]
    else:
        return None

def restaurants_owned_by_this_username(request):
    """ for now only returns one restaurant """
    # TODO: will need to support multiple restaurants owned by one user in the future
    if request.method == "POST":
        body = unpack_request_body(request)
        username = body['username']
        restaurant_owned = find_restaurant_owned_by_a_username(username)
        if restaurant_owned:
            serializer =  RestaurantSerializer(restaurant_owned, context={'request': request})
            return JsonResponse({'result': serializer.data})
        else:
            return JsonResponse({'result': None})
    else:
        error_message = "This method only responds to POST"
        print(error_message)
        return JsonResponse({'error': error_message})
```

urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^api/restaurants-owned', csrf_exempt(views.restaurants_owned_by_this_username), name="restaurants-owned"),
]
```

models.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Restaurant(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=False, blank=False)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, models.SET_NULL, related_name="restaurants", null=True, blank=True)

    address1 = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=False, blank=False)
    address2 = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=False, blank=False)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=2, null=False, blank=False)
    zip_code = models.CharField(max_length=5, null=False, blank=False)

    lat = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=7, null=True, blank=True)
    lng = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=7, null=True, blank=True)
```

I now hit the endpoint like `POST http://localhost:8000/api/restaurants-owned/ {"username": "codyc4321"}`

I get

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "user-detail". You may have failed to include the related model in your API, or incorrectly configured the `lookup_field` attribute on this field.
```

I have been looking up this error message, and after reading the ways to "solve" it, still don't understand it. It doesn't seem people are explaining what it means. I don't want a user-detail view, I only included user as a foreign key for who owns the restaurant. As the `views.py` shows, I solved this error once and didn't understand how it worked.

How can I stop this error message in the future and what is Django trying to say with it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "user-detail"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40073205/django-core-exceptions-improperlyconfigured-could-not-resolve-url-for-hyperlink)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django Rest Framework - Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "user-detail"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20550598/django-rest-framework-could-not-resolve-url-for-hyperlinked-relationship-using)